# How can I tell that a certificate is a root certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, mobile-device-management, configuration-profiles, mdm

[image]

Are these certificates root certificates or not and how can I disable them if they are?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to [Lists of available trusted root certificates in iOS](https://support.apple.com/HT204132) on Apple's website. This resource also provides links to lists of root certificates for specific versions of iOS, macOS, watchOS and tvOS.

Typically, to remove a root certificate on an iOS device one would follow this process:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap on General
3. Tap on Profiles (NOTE: if the Profiles screen is empty then there’s nothing to delete)
4. Select the Profile you want to delete
5. Tap on Delete Profile
6. Enter your passcode
7. Tap on Delete again to confirm the deletion

Based on your screenshots and tags it's clear you're referring to a device that is controlled by a Mobile Device Management (MDM) process. If you can't remove the certificate(s) you want to with the above process you will need to contact your employer/school/etc to seek assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The list of installed profiles in your screenshot does not contain any root certificates. There are two certificates at the bottom, but those are signing certificates, and also not root certificates.